# How to nest a ListView inside a PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a horizontal PageView with some nested vertical LIstView on each page.

the Issue is I am unable to scroll those nested listview as I am only registering the `PageView` gestures.

**note:** when I use `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` inside `customSCrollView` with no limits the scroll is actually active but everything else no

this is what the code look like

```
class ProductDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ProductDetailState();
}

class ProductDetailState extends State {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: NestedScrollView(
//                 physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                headerSliverBuilder:
                    (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
                  return <Widget>[];
                },
                body: PageView( // this is a pageView container
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: [
                       SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text('index $index'),
                              );
                            },
                            childCount: 10
                          ),
                        )
                       ]
                    ),
                    CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: [
                       SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (context, index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text('index $index'),
                              );
                            },
                            childCount: 10
                          ),
                        )
                       ]
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 30,
//               child: 
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NestedScrollView` is messing up here. Since, you're not using `headerSliverBuilder`, you can just remove the widget entirely. Here's the working code.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    child: PageView(
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('index $index')),
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => ListTile(title: Text('index $index')),
                childCount: 20,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: this actually works, though i still don't get the gesture registering race between those widgets +1

Comment: @bihireboris When you use `ListView` inside `NestedScrollView`, it gives preference to the later which is why the `ListView` doesn't scroll. There could be workarounds to make that happen but I didn't try anything on my own.